# Rewrite URL to MP4 video with nginx

Tags: nginx, redirect, video-streaming

I want to rewrite `example.com/videos/name/` to the MP4 file `videos/name.mp4` and serve it with content type `video/mp4` as if the user would have requested the video directly with `example.com/videos/name.mp4`.

How can I do that with `nginx`?

Comment: If you implement a redirect then browsers will make a second request for the `.mp4` URL and you don't have to worry about the `content-type` for the redirect.  However, it kinda sounds like you actually want to rewrite the URL (which doesn't change the URL) instead of a redirect (which does change the URL.)  Is that true?

Comment: Oh yes, I mean rewrite instead of redirect. I have changed the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it:

```
location = /videos/ {
    types { } default_type "video/mp4";

    rewrite ^/name/$ /videos/name.mp4 last;
}
```